# Popular classe com json

Tags: c#, json

Tenho esse json vindo do meu serviço

```
{
    "CorIndicador":"VERMELHO",
    "DadosIndicador":"{\"Previsto\":25784.686452608872,\"Realizado\":95258.9557949728}",
    "TipoIndicador":1
}
```

E tenho essa classe

```
public class FaturamentoResponse
{
   public string CorIndicador { get; set; }
   public double Previsto { get; set; }
   public double Realizado { get; set; }
}
```

quando eu faço isso

```
var resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FaturamentoResponse>(response.Content);
```

a **var resp** vem CorIndicador apenas populada. Previsto e Realizado está vindo "0". Tenho certeza que é por causa do DadosIndicador. Como eu populo as properties Previsto e Realizado.

**EDIT1**

olhando bem minha pasta, vi essa classe

```
[DataContract]
    public class DadosResponse
    {
        [DataMember]
        public TipoIndicador TipoIndicador { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string CorIndicador { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string DadosIndicador { get; set; }
    }
```

Acho que ela é a que deve receber o json, certo?

**EDIT2**
Fiz da forma abaixo e deu esse erro

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value
>   "{"Previsto":55022.101316145665,"Realizado":19938.330920384418}"  to
>   type 'Operacional.Models.DadosResponse'. Path 'DadosIndicador', line
>   1, position 112. ocorreu

**EDIT3**

Troquei pela classe que eu havia postado a **DadosResponse** e lá o **DadosIndicador** é `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa notar que, na verdade, `DadosIndicador` é uma *string*.

Você precisa:

- arrumar o JSON;
- ou personalizar o deserializador;
- ou usar a propriedade como *string*;
- ou deserializá-la separadamente.

Aqui vai um exemplo de como fazer da última maneira citada

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var response = new 
        {
            Content = @"{""CorIndicador"": ""VERMELHO"", ""DadosIndicador"": ""{\""Previsto\"":25784.686452608872, \""Realizado\"":95258.9557949728} "",""TipoIndicador"":1}"
        };

        var resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FaturamentoResponse>(response.Content);

        Console.WriteLine(resp.DadosIndicador);

        var dados = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DadosResponse>(resp.DadosIndicador);

        Console.WriteLine(dados.Previsto);
        Console.WriteLine(dados.Realizado);
    }
}

public class FaturamentoResponse
{
    public string CorIndicador { get; set; }
    public string DadosIndicador { get; set; }  
    public int TipoIndicador { get; set; }
}

public class DadosResponse
{        
    public double Previsto { get; set; }
    public double Realizado { get; set; }
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yGkLSO)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Para você desserializar um objeto com sucesso você deve ter as classes correspondentes no model.

Então se sua estrutura de JSON é:

```
{
    "CorIndicador":"VERMELHO",
    "DadosIndicador":"{\"Previsto\":25784.686452608872,\"Realizado\":95258.9557949728}",
    "TipoIndicador":1
}
```

Então sua classe model deve ser:

```
public class FaturamentoResponse
{
    public string CorIndicador { get; set; }
    public DadosResponse DadosIndicador { get; set; }
    public int TipoIndicador { get; set; }
}

public class DadosResponse
{        
    public double Previsto { get; set; }
    public double Realizado { get; set; }
}
```

E para desserializar você ainda pode usar:

```
var resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FaturamentoResponse>(response.Content);
```